# jquerymobile - Chrome won't prompt to save password on standard POST submit

Tags: google-chrome, jquery-mobile, passwords

Chrome doesn't seem to be consistent regarding when it prompts to save password.  Consider the following two processes from my web site...

1. Go to home page
2. Click Login (this takes you to Login.php)
3. Enter a login/password
4. You're logged in now, but Chrome **did not** prompt you to save the password

However...

1. Go to home page
2. Click Login
3. **Refresh the page**
4. Enter login/password
5. You're logged in now, and Chrome **did** prompt to save the password...

What gives?  The only difference is hitting "refresh".  The code for Login.php is very very simple... essentially:

```
<form id="LoginForm1" action="Login.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="UserName" />
  <input type="password" name="Password" />
  <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

There's javascript (jquery-1.7.2 and jquery.mobile-1.3.0) on the main page, but not on Login.php.  It seems to carry over, though, because the styling of the form on Login.php looks like jquerymobile until the refresh.  Can anyone explain this behavior?  (And furthermore, why does jquery/jquerymobile inhibit the Save Password feature?)

Thanks in advance... this is my first question asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Short answer***

The link from my homepage to Login.php needed **data-ajax="false"** in the **a href** tag.

After I re-included jquery-mobile to Login.php, the **form** tag on Login.php also needed **data-ajax="false"**.

***Long answer***

**Part 1**

After more digging, I found that the normal behavior for jquery-mobile [is to "hijack" all **a href** links and process them through its ajax functionality](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0/docs/widgets/navigation/).  This means it was transferring to Login.php as an ajax-style transfer, instead of a standard **a href** transfer.  A standard transfer checks Login.php for its specifically declared javascript include files, but the ajax transfer carried over the javascript includes from the homepage.

However... when you force the browser to only look at Login.php (by clicking refresh) it found that there weren't any javascript includes, and so Chrome looked at the naked page ane dealt with it properly.

**Part 2**

You have to meet several requirements for Chrome to prompt to save a password.  Among them include:

1. You have to use a **form** element
2. You have to use a **submit**, not a button
3. The submit has to be a real submit.  (If you override the submit functionality with some javascript/Ajax... it (probably) won't prompt to save a password.)
4. The form has to be visible when the page loads.

When working with jquery-mobile, 3 and 4 can trip you up.

With respect to 3...

jquery-mobile automatically hijacks the form submit process, the way it does with links... so it's necessary to add **data-ajax="false"** to the **form** element to prevent it from doing that.

With respect to 4...

The first version of my website had a login [**panel**](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/panels/) on the home page where the login button revealed the panel from "underneath" the page.  This method would not prompt for a password until I forced the panel [to be visible on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762831/jquery-mobile-1-3-panel-always-visible).

Since I didn't want the login panel always to be visible on the home page, I decided to use a separate login page (Login.php).  However jquery-mobile's inherent way of treating links to separate pages is to hijack them with its ajax functionality... which the browser interprets as staying on the same page.  So for Chrome, navigating to Login.php was the same as using a hidden panel... because Chrome interpreted both requests as staying on the home page... and in either case, the form element was not visible when the page originally loaded.