# onLoad jQuery Mobile panel when opening website

Tags: jquery, mobile, panel, onload

jQuery Mobile have recently launched a new 'Panel' feature in 1.3.0, which I need to basically open straight away as the page loads.

The link to open the 'Panel' is

```
<a href="#" class="jqm-navmenu-link" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext">Navigation</a>
```

And the code for the panel itself is...

```
<div data-role="panel" class="jqm-nav-panel jqm-navmenu-panel" data-position="left" data-display="reveal" data-theme="c">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="d" data-divider-theme="d" data-icon="false" data-global-nav="docs" class="jqm-list">
        <li data-role="list-divider">jQuery Mobile Demos</li>
        <li><a href="../">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="intro/">Introduction</a></li>
        <li><a href="examples/">Demo Showcase</a></li>
        <li><a href="faq/">Questions & Answers</a></li>
        <li><a href="intro/rwd.php">Going Responsive</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider">Widget reference</li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- /panel -->
```

I'm not sure how this is achievable, but I'd be grateful for any help/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!
For anyone looking, visit this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762831/jquery-mobile-1-3-panel-always-visible), alternatively, view the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/EkbYe/)

Or read this...

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
$( "#mypanel" ).panel( "open"); });
```